# What does the tangent line to a general curved electric field line denote?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Just want to see the tangent line which indicates the line of electric force. What is tangent line?

Comment: Obviously it's the direction of the electrical force - just as the normal to the line is the equipotential surface. But you might have to explain a bit more clearly what you are asking... it doesn't seem to me like this is the answer you are looking for. Is it?

Comment: just help me by showing what is tangent line that indicates the direction.pls pls.

Comment: Try to be constructive in writing a question. Please try to make a good title that reflects the query and not some bunch of words or phrases; don't write things while keeping on your _caps lock_; this increases the vagueness and nothing else. Also, please use relevant tags only: how is [tag: electrical-engineering] relevant here? Do keep these points in mind when post a new query in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangent line, in general, is the line that follows the gradient of a curve at a specific point - like in this diagram:

[image]

The blue line is the tangent of the red line at the point where they touch.

Comment: @ffahim: If it is so; if it really helped you, then accept the answer and upvote it. Good answer deserves that.